# "Encoding failed" FFMPEG laravel ProtoneMedia\\LaravelFFMpeg\\Exporters\\EncodingException(code: 0):

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

tried to upload a video with ffmpeg, got an error

```
(ProtoneMedia\\LaravelFFMpeg\\Exporters\\EncodingException(code: 0): Encoding failed at /app/vendor/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/src/Exporters/EncodingException.php:12)
```

the strange thing is that there are only a few videos that can and can't be uploaded like an example data with video:

1. test-video1.mp4 (success)
2. test-video2.mp4 (failed)

**Implementation**

```
$mediaName= "425d17680ae04eb853d4c2e1da24a5aa.mp4"
$mediadisk= "media"
$tmpPath = $file->store('/tmp', temp_disk'));
$pathPrefix = 'member/2';

        $ffMpeg = FFMpeg::fromDisk(config('temp_disk'))->open($tmpPath);

        $dimension = $ffMpeg->getVideoStream()->getDimensions();

        $ffMpeg
            ->export()
            ->toDisk($mediadisk)
            ->save($videoPath = "{$pathPrefix}/videos/{$mmediaName}")
            ->getFrameFromSeconds(5)
            ->export()
            ->toDisk($thumbnailDisk = config('asset-inventory.image_disk'))
            ->save($thumbnailPath = $pathPrefix . '/media/thumbnail/' . $mediaName . '.png');

        return [
            'path' => $videoPath,
            'thumbnail_disk' => $thumbnailDisk,
            'thumbnail_path' => $thumbnailPath,
            'duration' => $ffMpeg->getDurationInSeconds(),
            'width' => $dimension->getWidth(),
            'height' => $dimension->getHeight()
        ];
```

Result :

```
ffmpeg failed to execute command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i'

"[object] (ProtoneMedia\\LaravelFFMpeg\\Exporters\\EncodingException(code: 0): Encoding failed at /app/vendor/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/src/Exporters/EncodingException.php:12)
[stacktrace]
#0 /app/vendor/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/src/Exporters/MediaExporter.php(172): ProtoneMedia\\LaravelFFMpeg\\Exporters\\EncodingException::decorate(Object(FFMpeg\\Exception\\RuntimeException))
```

**FFMPEG Version :**

````
ffmpeg version 4.3.2-0+deb11u2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100```
````